# An unknown server-side error occurred, Bad app: ⁨/../../. App(ipa) paths need to be absolute or an URL to a compressed file

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

While I am running the `JsonScript` in the appium inspector

**Environment used:**

```
"platformName": "iOS",
"deviceName": "iPhone Simulator",
"platformVersion": "12.1",
"app": "⁨⁨/../../...ipa", 
"automationName":
"XCUITest", 
"noReset": true
```

It is not starting the appium inspector and throwing the error

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Bad app: ⁨⁨/../../. App(ipa) paths need to be absolute
>   or an URL to a compressed file

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is create the **app** folder in the project root folder. Move your **filename.ipa** file inside app folder. Your app path will be

```
"app": "/app/filename.ipa"
```

Comment: Still the issue remains the same i have the path  **/Users⁩/abcdl⁩/⁨Library/Developer⁩/⁨Xcode⁩/⁨DerivedData⁩/⁨xtz-dcmbsizawzkjjvbmwhtnixvtzklt⁩/⁨Build⁩/⁨Products⁩/app/VeriDocG.ipa**

Comment: yes i just tried  **"app" : app/appli.ipa** but still it throws the same error , also can you suggest me root directory means in which sense you are talking about

Comment: i mean root directory of the project i.e where you can fine the folder like src, pom.xml etc

Comment: No, its not working can you please suggest any other way

Comment: can you add the appium server log?